# Can't run my java .exe program. How do I troubleshoot this ? ("A Java exception has occured") and JNI problem

Tags: java, exception, jar, exe, launch4j

My problem is that I created a Java app that I exported to .jar if I open it in .jar it works perfectly but I'd like to make it an .exe app so I've tried launch4j but if I try to use the .exe file created I get "Error, A JNI error has occured, please check your installation etc..." and "A Java Exception has occured" also I don't know if it's useful but if I try to test the wrapper in Launch4j I get the same messages and this on the log :

```
Executing:C:\Users\edena\Documents\CGen.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: CodeGenerator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I've already tried to see if the problem was from my Java version but it says it's the latest. Also, I tried deleting metadata in Eclipse and doing the process again but it didn't work

Comment: why not just keep it as a jar?

Comment: this error seems straightforward enough: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: CodeGenerator has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: Yes I know I read it too that's why I tried in vain to update my java but unfortunately it wasn't the right approach

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to execute a class that was compiled with a JDK 11 with a JRE 8.

You can either specify the target version 8 when you compile your classes, or set the min version in your launch4j configuration:

```
  <jre>
    ...
    <minVersion>11</minVersion>
    ...
  </jre>
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried doing the second method it says that the JRE version can only be set as the following "0.0.0" so writing "11.0.0" won't work and I searched on the web but it says that there is no such thing as a JRE 11

Comment: @edenannonay so can you compile for java 8?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

I found out how to make it work. I went in my IDE (Eclipse) and right clicked on my project then Properties>Java Compiler then de-checked "Use compliance from execution environment 'JAVA SE-11' on the 'Java BuildPath>I then set the compiler compliance level on 1.4.